# How to integrate external chatbot inside PowerBI dashboard?

Tags: powerbi, chatbot

I've created a versatile chatbot powered by Azure OpenAI. It's a conversation connoisseur, trained to decode your natural language questions and dish out insightful answers. Just ask away, and it'll be your trusty ally in navigating information.

I'd like to inquire about the possibility of integrating a chatbot within Power BI. If feasible, could you elaborate on the integration process?

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple (maybe more) options:

1. Use the [HTML Content](https://www.html-content.com/) custom visual with `IFRAME`.
2. Create a PowerApp for your chatbot, and embed this into Power BI via the [Power App visual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual).

Does your chatbot have anything to do with the Power BI report itself?

Comment: I have tried the first option, but I failed that visual is suitable for web page but for web app I am getting error.

Comment: What error you getting? It will work so long as the app doesn't have CORS.

Comment: I've successfully integrated the web app within the HTML content, but I'm encountering a 'You need to enable JavaScript to run this app' error within the Power BI dashboard.

Comment: Is this error in Power BI Desktop or when Published and viewed online?